# Video Drivers for Onboard GeForce 6150SE

Tags: drivers, nvidia

I'm currently using the proprietary driver (version current-updates). Everything's working okay, but if I try and watch a YouTube video or movie in full screen the playback is extremely choppy. Am I using the right drivers? Here is the output from sudo lshw -C video:

```
  foo@bar:~$ sudo lshw -C video
            [sudo] password for foo: 
                                    *-display               
                                    description: VGA compatible controller
                                    product: C61 [GeForce 6150SE nForce 430]
                                    vendor: nVidia Corporation
                                    physical id: d
                                    bus info: pci@0000:00:0d.0
                                    version: a2
                                    width: 64 bits
                                    clock: 66MHz
                                    capabilities: pm msi vga_controller bus_master        cap_list rom
                                    configuration: driver=nvidia latency=0
                                    resources: irq:22 memory:de000000-deffffff memory:c0000000-cfffffff memory:dd000000-ddffffff memory:dfd40000-dfd5ffff
```

Using Firefox with the latest version of Flash. It says the open source drivers are default, so I assume those are the one's being used when I don't have the proprietary drivers activated in "Additional Drivers". But the problem is still there regardless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to install the Proprietary drivers for your video card to work better for the time being, until the open source drivers gain better support.

Follow this question to install them: [Nvidia geforce 6150-unity 3d won't work](https://askubuntu.com/questions/106686/nvidia-geforce-6150-unity-3d-wont-work/106784#106784)