# Nvidia geforce 6150-unity 3d won't work

Tags: 11.10, nvidia, 3d

The Nvidia Geforce 6150 does not work with Unity. What should I do to fix it?

I am using Ubuntu 11.10.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know this video card is old but I have resolved several older Nvidia card issues using the latest Nvidia drivers.

To install the latest drivers (assuming you have alread installed the proprietary drivers from the **Additional Drivers** app, do the following:

In the terminal type: `sudo apt-add-repository ppa:ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates`

Then update your repositories by typing in the terminal this: `sudo apt-get update`.

Afterwards go to your **Update Manager**. An updated version of the Nvidia card will appear. Install it and reboot the PC.

If you have not yet installed the proprietary drivers then open your dash and type "Drivers". The **Additional Drivers** icon app should appear. Install the Nvidia recommended driver from the list and reboot.

From my experience this has solved a Geforce FX 5600 problem I had, a Geforce 6200 problem and another Geforce 6400.

Comment: it won't cause problem with suspend? can you tell me what the x-upadte is?

Comment: That is a PPA that includes the latest drivers for Intel, Ati & Nvidia. Basically when Nvidia or Ati come out with a new driver version, the PPA will update to the latest. It will not cause problems with supend. Tested here already. When you are satisfied with the answer please accept the answer to approve it.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, it was actually a case of *removing* the NVIDIA drivers.

My answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/121128) helped.

As a bonus, my whole system seems to be running much much faster. I think the Nvidia driver was buggy and slowing everything down and not recognizing my video card's capability.

Comment: Try not to copy and paste answers - just link your previous answer if you consider that it answers the question.  The reason is simple - a change in one answer will be still be correct with a linked answer whereas a duplicate answer will be potentially wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You could try an older `nvidia-173` driver from the repositories. Ii's not a fix, rather a workaround, but it worked for some, according to comments [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nvidia-graphics-drivers/+bug/728745), ...that is, if you don't mind suspend to RAM not working.

As for a proper fix, it seems that anything prior to Geforce 8xxx is considered too old for Unity, which seems like a fair deal. [The first 8xxx series were released five years ago, in 2007](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GeForce_8_Series#Technical_summary).