# How to fix random crashes using NVIDIA GeForce 6150SE nForce 430?

Tags: drivers, graphics, nvidia-geforce

I have installed ubuntu 12.10 and my computer has the graphics card:

> NVIDIA GeForce 6150SE nForce 430

My screen usually crashes with raster lines, flashing, and other junk on the screen.

What is the best way to get Ubuntu running correctly on this graphics card?

Comment: Check this [answer](http://askubuntu.com/questions/106686/nvidia-geforce-6150-unity-3d-wont-work/106784#106784) and see if it solves your problem.

Comment: My GeForce 6150SE nForce 430 crashes the same way and I am using the Linux amd-64 3.5.0-25-generic cpu, but I find it only crashes when I click on the Launch button in Unity.

Answer (score 2):

Did you install the nvidia-current or the updates device module?

I have the same card:

```
*-display               
   description: VGA compatible controller
   product: C61 [GeForce 6150SE nForce 430]
```

Prior to 12.04 I used the Nvidia current driver, but with 12.04 I found it best to stay with the Nouveau driver because of the same problem you have.  Apart from turning the card output off for a few seconds during login when the desktop first comes up it appears to work very well indeed.

Comment: thanks for your comments but as i told before i am totally new to ubuntu plz mention the step one by one,, so that i can understand

Comment: we need to know what you've done so far.  Did you install nvidia-current drivers, or nothing at all?

Comment: nothing have done,, actually i don't know how to install and from where i can get that drivers

Answer (score 0):

Mine was fixed putting with `pci=nomsi,noaer` on Linux boot options.

The options from the recommended nvidia "Chapter 8" did not worked for me: http://http.download.nvidia.com/XFree86/Linux-x86_64/325.15/README/commonproblems.html

It was about a bad Asus motherboard for what I had understood from https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1234983&p=8387532#post8387532