# Possible Hardrive problem after installing Ubuntu 14.04.2

Tags: 14.04

I received an old desktop computer that was going to be given away. It is a Compaq Presario SR5710F. They said it was virus-free. It was running Windows Vista fine (well, slowly, but it was actually functioning).

I tried installing Ubuntu 14.04.2 32-bit onto the computer and it technically booted (for about a minute, there was nothing going to the monitor) and then the home screen popped up. I was unable to move the mouse and could not click on anything. I tried a copy of Tails and for some reason it worked just fine. I also tried Lubuntu (I don't remember which distro) and that failed on me too.

Does it sound like something is wrong with the hard drive?

Answer (score 0):

Tails will run on RAM and takes special care not to use swap, so it is possible that there is something wrong with your hard drive. However there are other things that can cause the same problem, for example the graphics processor.

According to Google, the Compaq Presario SR5710F has either an NVIDIA GeForce 6150SE integrated graphics processor or an NVIDIA nForce 430 GPU. See: [What's the correct driver to use with a GeForce 6150SE nforce 430 on Lubuntu 14.10?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/588538/whats-the-correct-driver-to-use-with-a-geforce-6150se-nforce-430-on-lubuntu-14).