# Lubuntu 18.04 NVIDIA

Tags: drivers, nvidia, 18.04, graphics, lubuntu

Lubuntu 18.04. Installed today. Selected update and install proprietary drivers during install.

The ubuntu tool detects nothing:

[image: Sofware & Updates - Additional Drivers]

```
lspci | grep -i vga
00:0d.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation C61 [GeForce 6150SE nForce 430] (rev a2)
```

The following command does nothing. No error message, nothing.

```
sudo ubuntu-drivers devices
```

antiX has a driver install routine that installed the driver, but I didn't like that distro. I liked Lubuntu because it made NVIDIA easy. That no longer seems to be the case.

How do I get this driver installed, please?

Comment: I made a mistake, and edited my comment to reflect:
Lubuntu 18.04

Answer (score 0):

According to this question

[What's the correct driver to use with a GeForce 6150SE nforce 430 on Ubuntu and Ubuntu flavours?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/588538/whats-the-correct-driver-to-use-with-a-geforce-6150se-nforce-430-on-ubuntu-and)

Your card needs `nvidia-304` which is not supported any more.  You can see the bug report [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nvidia-graphics-drivers-304/+bug/1737750).

Comments in the bug report give a workaround involving installing a patch and compiling the driver yourself. I actually did get this to work (but not without significant effort) on a laptop with a Geoforce 8300 card.

Comment: https://www.geforce.com/drivers/results/123709    it seems 6150SE supported by the proprietary drivers from the manufacture website

Comment: That link goes to the 304 drivers which do not work anymore as explained in the bug report I linked.

Comment: Ok i can't confirm this (bug) but  the release date of the drivers was Tue Sep 19, 2017, free open source drivers especially for Nvidia (most) cards is better than the proprietary drivers is more optimized

Comment: It seem the post was 3 years, 7 months ago plus the last test was on Ubuntu versions 16.04 did you tested on 18.04 with the drivers that was released on Tue Sep 19, 2017 from Nvidias webpage?

Comment: Im asking im not judging because i know people that they have nvidia cards

Comment: I have a newer card the 1050 and it works great; it's just these old cards that need the 304 driver that are in trouble