# How do I get 1280x1024 resolution?

Tags: display-resolution

I'm coming back to lubuntu after a few years. I'm on an AMD Athlon x64 with 2.75 GB ram. I have installed lubuntu 18.04 Alternate 64-bit. I also tried the 18.04 Desktop 64-bit.

A few years ago, I was able to get 1280x1024 res (on a different computer), but not this time. For now, I would even be happy with a command that I have to enter each time I boot. I know the monitor can handle 1280x1024.

Any help appreciated. Otherwise, everything is great.

```
$ xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1024 x 768, maximum 4096 x 4096
VGA-1 connected primary 1024x768+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y 
axis) 0mm x 0mm
1024x768      60.00* 
800x600       60.32    56.25  
848x480       60.00  
640x480       59.94
```

Here's all I know at this point:

[image: image capture of specs]

```
*-display
description: VGA compatible controller
product: C61 [GeForce 6150SE nForce 430]
vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
physical id: d
bus info: pci@0000:00:0d.0
version: a2
width: 64 bits
clock: 66MHz
capabilities: pm msi vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
configuration: driver=nouveau latency=0
resources: irq:23 memory:fd000000-fdffffff memory:d0000000-dfffffff 
memory:fc000000-fcffffff memory:c0000-dffff
```

This works for me but must be re-entered after each boot.

```
xrandr --newmode "1280x1024_60.00"  108.88  1280 1360 1496 1712  1024 
1025 1028 1060  -HSync +Vsync
xrandr --addmode VGA-1 1280x1024_60.00
xrandr --output VGA-1 --mode 1280x1024_60.00
```

Newbies like me should follow this guide: http://www.arunviswanathan.com/node/53

Comment: 1. Which version of Lubuntu is it (16.04.1 LTS or 18.04.1 LTS or some other version)? 2. Please specify the graphics card/chip (brand name and model). -- There may be more questions later on, and your answers will help us help you ...

Comment: Thanks it's 18.04. This is a (new) secondhand computer which I know little about. Will get back with more specs once I find them.

Comment: You can try different versions live (booted from a live USB pendrive or DVD disk) and 'Try Lubuntu' -- you need not install anything. Run `xrandr` to list the available resolutions (and edit your original question to tell us the result. Indent each line of the output 4 spaces to render it as 'code').

Comment: The following link may help you select version of Lubuntu (and find it), [How to select the version and flavour of Ubuntu](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2230389&p=13540865#post13540865).

Comment: Thanks great suggestions.. I've got some pressing work to do but plan to get back with specs re graphics card etc.

Comment: Just added all I know about this computer. Thanks.

Comment: It seems that Lubuntu 18.04 LTS does not detect the graphics chip/card and cannot get better resolution than 1024x768. I suggest that you download Lubuntu **desktop** iso file of 16.04.1 LTS and 'Try Lubuntu' live (in a USB pendrive or DVD disk). Sometimes older versions are better at recognizing and using old hardware.

Comment: Thanks, I tried 16.04 as suggested but got the same options for resolution. I do not know if the recently added info helps. I was following the lead here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/31618/how-can-i-find-my-hardware-details

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding newmode with Xrandr - "800x480\_60.00"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/890231/adding-newmode-with-xrandr-800x480-60-00)

Comment: It is an old nvidia graphics chip, and Lubuntu is using the free nouveau driver. You could try a proprietary nvidia driver, which might work better or not at all. The proprietary driver should be installed in the installed Lubuntu system (not in a live system). I can also support the tip 'Adding newmode with Xrandr', which might work.

Comment: Thanks, I installed 16.04 and am looking at different ways to get around the problem mentioned here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/588538/whats-the-correct-driver-to-use-with-a-geforce-6150se-nforce-430-on-ubuntu-and I too have had random screen freezing with this computer using Windows 7, XP and both versions of lubuntu. I thought it was RAM or maybe bad sectors in HD. But I'm thinking it's the graphics.

Comment: Also looking into 'Adding newmode with Xrandr' - much appreciated.

Comment: Success getting 1280x1024 by following this page http://www.arunviswanathan.com/node/53 but I doubt it will persist after reboot.

Comment: Now that you made it work, it should be possible to put those actions into corresponding command lines in a shellscript and run that shellscript automatically at login (if no other method should work).

Comment: @sudodus Thanks, not sure if this is what you mean but I saved the xrandr commands as a hidden file /home/<~username>/.xprofile and it works great. I really appreciate your walking me thru this!

Comment: Am I right, that you have solved your problem?

Comment: Yes, I just did a fresh install of Lubuntu 18.04.1 LTS Desktop 64-bit and repeated the process. It works. A workaround for the issue of computer freezing is to use remote desktop with my Windows computer as server. Seems if I keep the RAM usage low for the Lubuntu computer it doesn't freeze. Not sure if that is an NVIDIA issue or just that the Lubuntu computer was tinkered with before I bought it. The freeze issue is probably best suited for another thread about hardware. Thanks again.